# Copy range of cells to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two tables on two sheets, I need to copy three chosen cells from first table and paste it in the table on the second sheet.

I recorded some actions and edited something there.
So it copies range B9:D9 and pastes it into next empty row(var vv) on second sheet.
The best way I see it works is I choose one cell (for example B10) and it takes range B10:D10 and paste it in another sheet, I just can't find the info how to make this kind of copypaste.

```
function copypaste() {
  var vv = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange('M1').getValue();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange(vv).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Sheet1\'$B9:D9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground(null);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
};
```

Comment: Hello Maxim! I don't quiet get which is the issue.

Comment: Hello! For now it pastes only B9:D9 range every time, but I need to choose cell I want.  Let's say I choose cell B11 and I want script to copy a range B11:D11 and paste it on second sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copypaste() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const vs = sh2.getRange('B9:D9').getValues();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow() + 1 , 2, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Takes the values from Sheet2!B9:D9 and pastes them into Sheet1 next empty row column B to D